# Update same row multiple times using MERGE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have @Product table. I want to Update this table from another temp table @TempProducts. Let's say I have,

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE(Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(255), Description NVARCHAR(255));
DECLARE @TempProducts TABLE(RowNumber int, Id INT, Name NVARCHAR(255), Description NVARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO @Products(Id,Name,Description) VALUES(1,'Name1','Desc1');

INSERT INTO @TempProducts(RowNumber,Id,Name,Description) VALUES(1,1,'NewName1',NULL);
INSERT INTO @TempProducts(RowNumber,Id,Name,Description) VALUES(2,1,NULL,'NewDesc1');
```

I want to update @Products from @TempProducts such that if Value is NULL then don't update otherwise UPDATE. My final output should be,

```
Id   Name       Description
---------------------------
1    NewName1   NewDesc1
```

It should UPDATE order by RowNumber. So I tried,

```
MERGE @Products P
USING (SELECT TOP (100000) Id, Name, Description FROM @TempProducts ORDER BY RowNumber) TP
    ON P.Id = TP.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET  Name = ISNULL(TP.Name,P.Name),
        Description = ISNULL(TP.Description,P.Description)
        -- OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, INSERTED.Name  ----
        ;
```

It gives me

```
Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.
```

This works but I need to put OUTPUT clause and OrderBy.

```
UPDATE  P
   SET  Name = ISNULL(TP.Name,P.Name),
        Description = ISNULL(TP.Description,P.Description)
FROM    @Products P
        INNER JOIN @TempProducts TP
            ON P.Id = TP.Id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work in case of Output ..

```
UPDATE  P
   SET  Name = ISNULL(TP.Name,P.Name),
        Description = ISNULL(TP.Description,P.Description)
        Output inserted.Id,inserted.Name 
FROM    @Products P
        INNER JOIN @TempProducts TP
            ON P.Id = TP.Id
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to use Order By

Comment: on which column you want order by and which table

Comment: Check RowNumber column. I want the Update to run in Order